# NERDTreeFocus CWD

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree, cwd

I'm trying to use :NERDTreeFocus `map <C-n> :NERDTreeFocus<CR>`.

I used to launch `gvim` from `~` then move in my project folder with NERDTree, then I changed the cwd to the project folder path with `cd` NERDTree shortcut. But if I move in a file then I press `<C-n>` (:NERDTreeFocus), the pwd will be again `~`.

Please help me to fix this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

It's about `autochdir`. See `:h 'autochdir'`. 
You can try

```
set noautochdir
```

Hope it helps.